# Creating a bulk insert dump file using SQL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create a bulk insert statement from a table using SQL syntax without invoking the mysqldump utility?

Keep in mind that the  `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'` will not work for me since it generates a CSV file and not the output in **BULK INSERT SQL** format as below

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1,2), (5,5), ...;
```

Comment: Bulk insert? where are you getting your data from? from another table? or you want to save it to a file?

Comment: I am getting it from a table and I want to save it in a file as a bulk insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
SELECT * FROM mytable INTO OUTFILE 'dump.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

and then postprocess the output CSV with sed/perl/python/shell/whateverelse to get SQL script.

For example in python:

```
import csv
with open('dump.csv',"rU") as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    with open("dump.sql","wb") as outf:
        for row in reader:
            outf.write('insert into mytable values ("'+ '","'.join(row)  +'");\n')
```

The script doesn't work around `Null`s and quote characters in columns values.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code in whatever programming language your are comfortable with and I will convert it.